# How to edit a label in a new childnode created in a tree view, all of this programatically c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, edit, child-nodes

I'm starting to use tree view.

What I'm trying to do is a browse folder form, when the user clicks into a folder, it will display subfolders inside, all of this in a tree view, what I'm trying to do is create a new folder inside of a selected node:

this is an example:

```
Home ------->Folder1
    |------->Folder2
```

When click Make new folder button and I have selected "Folder1"

create a new childnode inside of Folder1 and start editing it.

```
Home -----> Folder1 --->BeginEditNewFolder
    |-----> Folder2
```

whis is what I have:

```
TreeNode NodeTocreate = new TreeNode();
NodeTocreate.ImageIndex = 0;
NodeTocreate.Text = string.Empty;
tvRemoteDirectory.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(NodeTocreate);
// <--- LINE OF CODE HERE TO START EDITING THAT NODE"
```

and this is What I have in the AfterLabelEdit event to get the name typed:

```
private void tvRemoteDirectory_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
{
    MakeDirectory = e.Label;
}
```

How can I start editing that new folder created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your TreeView control has the LabelEdit property set:

```
tvRemoteDirectory.LabelEdit = true;
```

then just call BeginEdit on the SelectedNode:

```
NodeTocreate.BeginEdit();
```